# LINQ Selecting rows where a column value IS NULL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
var myRows = myContext.MyTable
    .Where(v => v.MyColumn == null);
```

This does not select any rows from the table, even though there are many rows where "MyColumn is null"?

I need to select the rows where MyColumn contains null.

I realise that in T-SQL I'd have to use the "IS NULL" operator, but how can I select the rows I want in Linq?

I am using Entity Framework 5.0.

If this should be working, let me know, as my bug must be elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It would seem that the problem is to do with a small detail I thought was irrelevant. I am not actually comparing to the 'null' constant value.  I am comparing to a variable that I have set to null (in my case a string or DateTime?).  So I say myValue = null; ... (v => v.MyColumn == myValue).  Comparing to null returns the rows, comparing to myValue returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 3):

One common reason why this may not be working is if you map a nullable DB column (say, `MyColumn INTEGER NULL`) to a non-nullable field of a C# class (say, `int MyColumn` instead of `int? MyColumn`).

Make sure that `MyColumn` is of nullable type to fix this problem: other than that, your expression is correct, EF will correctly translate it to `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be working as is
Edit : Potential thing to check, is the column correctly noted as nullable in your edmx? I'm guessing if not it could be an issue